# Readers-writer lock (writer preferred) implementation

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, semaphore

I've read up on Readers-writer lock on wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock but tried using only one counter and one lock.

I'm curious to know whether this implementation is valid. If yes, do you think this would be enough for a technical interview.

```
            read() {
                lock g;
                while (num_of_writers > 0) {
                    g.wait(); // always yield to writers
                }
                doRead();
                unlock g;
            }

            write() {
                lock g;
                numOfWriters++; // let all the writers to queue up here
                unlock g;

                lock g;
                doWrite();
                num_of_writers--;
                g.notify();
                unlock g;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation looks like it correctly implements a valid lock, but it does *not* reliably prioritize writers (as stated in your title).

In particular, imagine `doWrite()` is a long-running operation currently executing with `num_of_writers==1`. During its execution many new reader and writer threads arrive at a `read()` or `write()` call. When the current writer unlocks `g`, there may be several writers queued up on their first `lock g` statement, but those writers are not given priority over readers who are queued at `lock g` or `g.wait()`. In fact depending on the implementation of the `notify`/`wait` condition variable, priority might actually be given to readers at `g.wait()`.

Also (and perhaps most importantly), this code does not allow for concurrent reads (`doRead()` executes inside a critical section of `g`), so this is not even technically a reader-writer lock.

Wrt technical interview, it's a decent counter-example... Give points to the candidate who can name these defects within a few minutes, and hire the one who can fix them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious to know whether this implementation is valid.

No. It is not valid. It doesn't allow "readers" to share access to the resource, and it doesn't reliably give priority to "writers." See Dan Bonachea's answer for details of both problems.